# Vagrant plugin demanding requirements of Ruby >= 2.0.0

Tags: ruby, vagrant

When I ran command `ruby -v`, it shows  `ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]` .

Then I ran command : 
 `sudo vagrant plugin install vagrant-librarian-chef` 
It shows :
 `/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:388:in ensure_required_ruby_version_met': ohai requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0. (Gem::InstallError)`
Anyone can help me! Thank you!

Comment: are you using rvm ?

Comment: I'm newbie about ruby!! so i don't know about rvm!! :(

Comment: what's the output of `sudo ruby -v`

Comment: how can i know I'm using rvm!! ?

Comment: sudo ruby -v : it shows : ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]

Comment: try running second command without `sudo`.

Comment: 'it shows same error :  /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:388:in ensure_required_ruby_version_met': ohai requires Ruby version >= 2.0.0. (Gem::InstallError)

Comment: well than uninstall `ruby` completely and manually install latest `ruby version`. For `ruby` development always use `rvm` or `rbenv`.

Comment: Problem: when you use ```sudo``` then you are using a different ruby than without ```sudo```.

Try to install ```rvm```, make sure you do not need ```sudo``` to install gems but install everything with your standard user privileges.

Comment: oh I uninstalled and then installed ruby 2.3 ..! I ran command " sudo ruby -v " It shows : ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
but still error !!!

Comment: I guess that's why Hashicorp writes all new software in Go :)

Comment: Hoang, what is the version of Vagrant on your machine?

Comment: I'm using Vagrant last version

Answer (score 0):

Its highly recommended that you use [RVM](https://rvm.io/) or [Rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv) while developing in Ruby to easily switch between Ruby versions and installed gems.

If you have followed tutorials, its most likely that you have RVM or Rbenv installed. First of all check if you do have rvm installed, by running `type rbenv` and `type rvm`. If any of them return a function, it means its installed.

If you have either of them installed, you mustn't use `sudo` while installing gems as they will get installed into machine Ruby, not RVM or Rbenv. So install vagrant without it.

If after all you don't have either, I would recommend installing RVM and installing all the gems under it. If you don't want to do that, you can try and upgrade ruby with and without sudo, so both of the versions you have are above  2.0